# Узнать размер listNode

Tags: java

Функция принимает listNode, как узнать ее размер? length и size не работают просто, есть вариант получить число ячеек? И по возможности напишите все функции по работе с листнодом пожалуйста.

Comment: Что такое `listNode`, что вы имеете в виду, какой тип у этой переменной? Точно тег `java`? В джаве нет функций, а есть методы. Задайте ваш вопрос более конкретно, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначный ответ. Приведите пример кода, если это нужно. Отредактировать вопрос можно по кнопке [edit] под вопросом.

Comment: Если `listNode` - это класс, взятый откуда-то или написанный вами, то приведите его код в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listNode не имеет размера - это элемент LinkedLista фактически (связного списка). По аналогии с массивом представляйте его, как ячейку массива. Однако есть большая разница. Размер связного списка не известен. И единственный способ его посчитать - пройтись от головы списка, до хвоста, где каждый элемент - это отдельный listNode. Сам по себе listNode не имеет функций. У него фактически есть: в лучшем случае, три значения: **val** (что записано в этом узле, например для
LinkList< Integer >
там будет записано какое-то число, для LinkedList< Car > будет храниться объект типа Car), есть ссылка на следующий элемент листа **next** (по ней вы и можете определить размер LinkedList: вы будете инкрементировать значение переменной счетчика начиная с головы, и пока не достигнете значения NULL - это будет означать что список закончился), и есть ссылка не предыдущий элемент **previous** (это при условии, что LinkedList двунаправленный, то есть каждый элемент имеет ссылку как на следующий элемент, так и на предыдущий).
Если вас интересовали не методы узла, а методы самого связного списка, то class LinkedList реализует интерфейсы Collection, List, Queue, соответственно он имеет все методы данных интерфейсов. В том числе и метод size().

Comment: У меня есть такое вот: public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode list1, ListNode list2). Как мне узнать размер лист1 и лист2?

Comment: Как я понимаю, вам дано две головы двух LinkedList. Вы находите длину первого листа: создаете временную переменную и ссылаете ее на голову первого листа. ListNode temp - list1. Потом с помощью while проходитесь по всему списку. while(temp!=null){size++; temp=temp.next()}. Вы на каждом этапе temp ссылаете на следующий элемент LinkedList. Когда вы дойдете до null - это будет означать что вы дошли до конца списка (хвоста), вы выйдете из цикла while и в переменной size у вас будет размер первого листа. Аналогично находите размер второго листа, и сравниваете два значения.